# Microsoft Chart. Legend Appears on Top of X Axis

Tags: charts, mschart

I created an Microsoft Chart in C# and added the following legend:

```
Legend legend = new Legend { 
  Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
  Docking = Docking.Bottom,
  Enabled = true,
  IsDockedInsideChartArea = false,
  TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Wide,  
};
```

Part of the legend appears on top of the X axis ... Any idea why?

How can I solve this? Can I add a top margin to the legend?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Can you also show the code you're using to add the legend to the Chart as well? I quickly tried your settings in my VB code and there is no overlap.

Answer (score 2):

In my code I let the Chart create the legend object itself, this is the VB code, but maybe it's useful to you:

```
aChart.Legends.Clear()
aChart.Legends.Add("Default")
aChart.Legends(0).BorderColor = Color.Black
aChart.Legends(0).Docking = Docking.Bottom
aChart.Legends(0).IsDockedInsideChartArea = False
aChart.Legends(0).TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Wide
aChart.Legends(0).Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a chart area:

```
p_Chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea(MAIN_CHART_AREA));

then set both your series and you legend to this area:

legend.DockedToChartArea = MAIN_CHART_AREA;

series.ChartArea = MAIN_CHART_AREA;
```